# Adding item to a recyclerview from dialog within a fragment class.?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment which must contains two recycler views. The view looks like follows. i need to add an item to the bottom recyclerview from a dialog. L'll post my code for the adapter class and xml. Please guide me to achieve this, a sample or a code is more than welcome.

[image: My Screen with two recyclerviews]

I've tried to pass the data from the dialog to the second recyclerview but it does not show the added item. Tell me anything i'm doing wrong here. Nothing i tried worked out to update my second recyclerview... :/

**My Fragment Class**

```
public class ReceiptFragment extends Fragment { //implements ContReceiptsAdapter.ItemOnClickListener

RecyclerView rv_rceipts, rv_addpayments;
RecyclerView.Adapter mContReceiptsAdapter,mAddPaymentsAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager1,mLayoutManager2;
View receipts_view;
private Context mContext;
ContReceiptsAdapter contReceiptsAdapter;
AddPaymentsAdapter addPaymentsAdapter;
//-- items in detailed dialog here
private ArrayList<Contract> contracts;
private ArrayList<AddPayments> payments;
private View linearLayout;
public View mRootView;

public ReceiptFragment() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    receipts_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_receipt, container, false);

    BuildReceiptsRV();
    BuildAddedPaymentsRV();
    // for setting the first item as default in the list
 //        onItemClicked(0);
    return receipts_view;

}

private void BuildReceiptsRV() {
    rv_rceipts = receipts_view.findViewById(R.id.rv_tobe_added);
    rv_rceipts.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv_rceipts.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    mLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv_rceipts.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager1);

    mContReceiptsAdapter = new ContReceiptsAdapter(getActivity(), ApplicationClass.contractList);
    rv_rceipts.setAdapter(mContReceiptsAdapter);
}

private void BuildAddedPaymentsRV() {
    rv_addpayments = receipts_view.findViewById(R.id.rv_added);
    rv_addpayments.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv_addpayments.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    mLayoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv_addpayments.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager2);

    mAddPaymentsAdapter = new AddPaymentsAdapter(getActivity(),ApplicationClass.paymentList);
    rv_addpayments.setAdapter(mAddPaymentsAdapter);
}

//change when click on change on item added to second rv
private void changeLayoutRV() {
    linearLayout = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_tobe_added);

    if (linearLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

**My Adapter for the First Recyclerview**

```
public class ContReceiptsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContReceiptsAdapter.ReceiptsViewHolder> {

//    private static Dialog AddItemDialog;
private ArrayList<Contract> contracts;
private ArrayList<AddPayments> payments = new ArrayList<>();
Context mContext;
String inPending;
//for the details dialog
EditText et_number, contract_id_val, product_type_val, mobile_number_ADialog, et_amount_add;
//    ImageView btn_add_item;
//--to set to add item dialog
public TextView contract_number, vehicle_number, contract_number_ADialog, vehicle_number_ADialog;
CheckBox checkbox_pending;

public ContReceiptsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contract> contractList) {
    contracts = contractList;
    mContext = context;
}

public class ReceiptsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_contract, tvVehicleN, tvContractType;
    ImageView btn_add_item;
    LinearLayout detailsLayout;

    public ReceiptsViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        detailsLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_details_item_id);
        tv_contract = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contract);
        tvVehicleN = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvVehicleN);
        tvContractType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvContractType);
        btn_add_item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_item);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ContReceiptsAdapter.ReceiptsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.receipt_tobe_added_rv_item, viewGroup, false);

    final ReceiptsViewHolder receiptsViewHolder = new ReceiptsViewHolder(view);

    //dialog ini
 //        ShowDetails();
    final Dialog detailedDialog = new Dialog(this.mContext);
    detailedDialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_details);

    receiptsViewHolder.detailsLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //click view dto show the detaileds view of the list item
            contract_number = detailedDialog.findViewById(R.id.contract_id_val);
            vehicle_number = detailedDialog.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_num_val);
            contract_number.setText(contracts.get(receiptsViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getContractNumber());
            vehicle_number.setText(contracts.get(receiptsViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getVehicleNumber());
            detailedDialog.show();
            detailedDialog.setCancelable(true);
//                    mListener.onItemClicked(contracts.indexOf(v.getTag()));
        }
    });

    return receiptsViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ContReceiptsAdapter.ReceiptsViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    viewHolder.itemView.setTag(contracts.get(i));
//        Contract currentItem = contracts.get(i);

    viewHolder.tv_contract.setText(contracts.get(i).getContractNumber());
    viewHolder.tvVehicleN.setText(contracts.get(i).getVehicleNumber());
    viewHolder.tvContractType.setText(contracts.get(i).getContractType());

    final Dialog AddItemDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    AddItemDialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_add_receipt);

    viewHolder.btn_add_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 //                ShowDetails();7
            contract_number_ADialog = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.contract_id_val_add);
            contract_number_ADialog.setText(contracts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getContractNumber());
            vehicle_number_ADialog = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.product_type_val_add);
            vehicle_number_ADialog.setText(contracts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getVehicleNumber());
            mobile_number_ADialog = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.et_number_add);
            mobile_number_ADialog.setText(contracts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getMobileNumber());
            checkbox_pending = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_pending_add);
            checkbox_pending.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(contracts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPendingState()));
            Button btn_cancel_receipt = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_receipt);
            Button btn_add_receipt = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_receipt);

            et_amount_add = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.et_amount_add);

            AddItemDialog.show();
            AddItemDialog.setCancelable(true);

            btn_cancel_receipt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AddItemDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            btn_add_receipt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AddData();

                    //add item to rv2
                    AddItemDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contracts.size();
}

private void addAnItem(AddPayments payment) {
    payments = ApplicationClass.paymentList;
    payments.add(payment);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void AddData() {

    String c_code = contract_number_ADialog.getText().toString();
    String c_mobile = mobile_number_ADialog.getText().toString();
    String c_amount = et_amount_add.getText().toString();

    AddPayments added_payment = new AddPayments(c_amount, c_code, c_mobile, "true");

    payments.add(added_payment);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
}
```

**My Adapter class for the Second Recyclerview**

```
public class AddPaymentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddPaymentsAdapter.AddPayViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<AddPayments> payments;
Context mContext;

public AddPaymentsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AddPayments> addPayments) {
    mContext = context ;
    payments = addPayments;
}

public class AddPayViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView tv_contract_d, tv_amount_d, tv_isPending_d, tv_mobile_num_d;
    ImageView btn_delete_item;
    ConstraintLayout addedPaymentLayout;

    public AddPayViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        addedPaymentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.added_payment_item_id);
        tv_contract_d = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contract_d);
        tv_amount_d = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount_d);
        tv_isPending_d = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_isPending_d);
        tv_mobile_num_d = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_mobile_num_d);
        btn_delete_item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_item);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AddPaymentsAdapter.AddPayViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.receipt_added_rv_item, viewGroup, false);

    final AddPayViewHolder addPayViewHolder= new AddPayViewHolder(view);

    return addPayViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AddPaymentsAdapter.AddPayViewHolder addPayViewHolder, final int i) {

    AddPayments currentItem = payments.get(i);

    addPayViewHolder.itemView.setTag(payments.get(i));

    addPayViewHolder.tv_contract_d.setText(payments.get(i).getAddContractCode());
    addPayViewHolder.tv_isPending_d.setText(payments.get(i).getAddIsPending());
    addPayViewHolder.tv_amount_d.setText(payments.get(i).getAddAmount());
    addPayViewHolder.tv_mobile_num_d.setText(payments.get(i).getAddMobile());

    addPayViewHolder.btn_delete_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //delete function
 //                Toast.makeText(mContext, "clicked delete icon inHoldernAdapter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            removeItem(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return payments.size();
}

private void removeItem(int i) {
    payments.remove(i);
    this.notifyItemRemoved(i);
}
}
```

Comment: have you notify adapters after adding items to the second adapter?

Comment: i did "this.notifyDataSetChanged();" .. is that the way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From your code in the adapter for the first recycler view you are using this method `AddData();` to add data. But this method adds data to `payments` which is the list where you hold the data which you want to show in the second recycler view but have no connection to it(it's just a field of the adapter class).
- The `this.notifyDataSetChanged()` notifies the current adapter for a change in data(first recycler view). You will need to add this data to the second recycler view adapter thou. You aren't doing that right now.

So a way would be to create a method inside of the fragment which takes a list of AddPayments as argument and add this data to the second recycler view adapater. It would be something like this:

Fragment method:

```
public void addSecondRVData(AddPayments itemToAdd) {
    mAddPaymentsAdapter.addNewPayment(itemToAdd);
}
```

Second recycler view method:

```
public void addData(AddPayments itemToAdd) {
    payments.add(itemToAdd);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged():
}
```

Dont forget to initialize the `payment` list in the second recycler view.

Then in the first adapter do smth like this:

```
private ReceiptFragment receiptFragment;

//Constructor
public ContReceiptsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contract> contractList, ReceiptFragment receiptFragment) {
   contracts = contractList;
   mContext = context;
   this.receiptFragment = receiptFragment;
}

//Use this to add elements to second rv
receiptFragment.addSecondRVData(newItem);
```

Hope this helps although is not the cleanest solution. Check the example I wrote here because can't test it at the moment.

Comment: thank you ebasha. i tried it but im a bit confused in the place 'addNewPayment'.. ?

Comment: My mistake. The method in second rv adapter should be called ‘addNewPayment’ not ‘addData’.

Comment: this part " mAddPaymentsAdapter.addNewPayment(itemToAdd);" --- addNewPayment is not identified withing my fragment class

Comment: Where i should call this addSecondRVData method from exactly..?

Comment: the error i get    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.comcredit.ccui.tobeadded.AddPaymentsAdapter.addNewPayment(com.comcredit.ccui.tobeadded.AddPayments)' on a null object reference
        at com.comcredit.ccui.tobeadded.ReceiptFragment.addSecondRVData(ReceiptFragment.java:90)
        at com.comcredit.ccui.tobeadded.ContReceiptsAdapter$2$2.onClick(ContReceiptsAdapter.java:169)

Comment: You must initialize the first Adapter from the fragment like this: `mContReceiptsAdapter = new ContReceiptsAdapter(getActivity(), ApplicationClass.contractList, this);`

Comment: i did initialized the both Adapters inside my fragment class. but its not passing data.. :/

Comment: somehow at the end i managed to do this. but ur guidance did helped alot. thanks.

Comment: Glad I helped :D